# Rust Strings and C variadic functions

Tags: c, rust, firebird, variadic-functions, ffi

I need pass a vector of Rust string to a [C variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#In_C). But I can't figure out what is the expected(`CString`, `[u8]`..) format.

References:

- API reference: [isc_event_block](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/Isc_event_block())
- My extern C declaration: [ibase](https://github.com/fernandobatels/rsfbclient/blob/a314bee70692483f7882f1bfd86dbfd57a94a698/rsfbclient-native/src/ibase.rs#L447)
- How I'm calling: [que_events](https://github.com/fernandobatels/rsfbclient/blob/a314bee70692483f7882f1bfd86dbfd57a94a698/rsfbclient-native/src/connection.rs#L601)
- C example: [api16](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/4c78ac43eb9494bd590d8d5801b25492e959f20a/examples/api/api16.c#L121)
- API implementation: [isc_event_block](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/4c78ac43eb9494bd590d8d5801b25492e959f20a/src/yvalve/alt.cpp#L53)

My `api16` example code version:

```c
strcpy (ids[0], "evento");
length = (short)  isc_event_block((char **) &event_buffer, (char **) &result_buffer, 1, ids[0], 0);
printf("event_buffer: '%s' %d\n", event_buffer, sizeof(event_buffer));
printf("result_buffer: '%s' %d\n", result_buffer, sizeof(result_buffer));
```

Result of version of `api16`:

```bash
event_buffer: 'evento' 8
result_buffer: '' 8
```

My Rust code:

```rust
let mut event_buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(256);
let mut result_buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(256);
let mut len = 0;
let names = "evento".to_string();

unsafe {
   len = self.ibase.isc_event_block()(
      event_buffer.as_mut_ptr() as *mut _,
      result_buffer.as_mut_ptr() as *mut _,
      names.len() as u16,
      names.as_ptr()
   );
   event_buffer.set_len(len as usize);
   result_buffer.set_len(len as usize);
}

println!("{:?} {:?}", len, names);
println!("{:x?} {:x?}", event_buffer, result_buffer);
println!("{:?} {:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&event_buffer.clone()), String::from_utf8_lossy(&result_buffer.clone()));
```

Result of my Rust code:

```bash
12 ["evento"]
[e0, 4f, 51, 28, a8, 7f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [0, 50, 51, 28, a8, 7f, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
"�OQ(�\u{7f}\0\0\0\0\0\0" "\0PQ(�\u{7f}\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

I already tried use `CString` or `CStr`, like [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/calling-c-function-with-string/41448/17).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing multiple things wrong in the rust version. For the first two arguments, you're intended to pass a pointer to a location that can hold a single pointer to a byte buffer. Instead, you're passing in a pointer to a byte buffer, so a pointer is getting written into that buffer, which isn't what you want.

Secondly, the `id_count` parameter corresponds to the number of strings you're passing as the variadic parameters, rather than the length of a single variadic string, meaning your c code just reads a bunch of uninitialized memory, which definitely isn't what you want. Additionally, that string does need to be null-terminated, and it isn't in your example, you do need `CString`. What you really want is something like this:

```
use std::ffi::{c_char, c_long, c_ushort, CStr, CString};
use std::ptr;
use std::slice;
use std::str;
fn main() {
    let mut event_buffer = ptr::null_mut();
    let mut result_buffer = ptr::null_mut();
    let names = CString::new("evento").unwrap();
    let len = unsafe {
        isc_event_block(
            &mut event_buffer,
            &mut result_buffer,
            1,
            names.as_ptr() as *mut c_char,
        )
    };
    debug_assert!(!event_buffer.is_null() && !result_buffer.is_null());
    let event_slice = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(event_buffer.cast(), len as usize) };
    let result_slice = unsafe { slice::from_raw_parts(event_buffer.cast(), len as usize) };
    let event_str = str::from_utf8(event_slice).unwrap();
    let result_str = str::from_utf8(result_slice).unwrap();
    println!("event: {event_str}");
    println!("result: {result_str}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=874372cd0299eba8e2830884e69303e0)

Adding a simple stub to print the string passed in, and write a couple of strings into the buffers, I got this:

```
"evento"
event: some events
result: some events
```

Comment: "Secondly, the id_count parameter corresponds to the number of strings"

My fail. In my original code I use the `names` as a vec<String> instead a single String. I forgot to change here.

Comment: For a single CString your answer works like a charm, but how I can use Vec<CString> in this place?

Comment: @Batels You'll have to use [libffi](https://crates.io/crates/libffi) or similar to call it with a dynamic number of arguments. If you only have a small number of different expected arg counts, manually writing out each of the possibilities by hand is an option, too.